# Download Button (It Open the file not Download the File)

Tags: html, css, download

Recently I have the problem that when I click the download button it always open not Download the File(RAR)

Here's the Web hope you can help me guys fixing this problem cause I'm good at making the button or a function

```css
 body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding:0:;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
 }

 /* Global */
 .container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 header ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }

 .button_1{
  height: 38px;
  background: #1b3f8b;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
 }

 .dark{
  padding: 15px;
  background:#35424a;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 h6{
  text-align:right;
 }

 /* Header */
 header{
  background:#B3E8FF;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding-top:30px;
  min-height:70px;
  padding-bottom:0;
  border-bottom:#80D9FF 3px solid;
 }

 header a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:16px;
 }

 header li{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
 }

 header #branding{
  float:left;
 }
 
 header #branding h1{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
 header nav{
  float:right;
  margin-top:10px;
 }

 header .highlight , header .current a{
  color:#1b3f8b;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 header a:hover{
  color:#cccccc;
  color-weight:bold;
 }

 /*showcase*/
 #showcase{
  min-height: 650px;
  background: url('../img/showcase.png') no-repeat 0 -5px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
 }

 #showcase h1{
  margin-top: 330px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
 }

 #showcase p{
  font-size: 20px;
 }

 /*newsletter*/
 #newsletter{
  padding: 15px;
  background: #B3E8FF;
  color: #ffffff;
 }

 #newsletter h1{
  float: left;
 }

 #newsletter form{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
 }
 
 #newsletter input[type="email"]{
  padding: 4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
 }

 /*boxes*/
 #boxes{
  margin-top: 20px;
 }

 #boxes .box{
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 #boxes .box img{
  width: 200px;
 }

 #boxes h1{
  text-align: center;
 }

 /*sidebar*/
 aside#sidebar{
  float:right;
  width:30%;
  margin-top:10px;
 }

 /*main-col*/
 article#main-col{
  float:left;
  width:65%;
 }

 footer{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #1b3f8b;
  background-color:#B3E8FF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
 }

 /*Repaint Gallery*/
 .gallery img{
  width:350px;
  height:140px;
 }
 
 th{
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color:#35424a;
  color:white;
 }

 td{
  padding:25px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 #repaintgallery table{
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
  /*Download Button*/
 .download{
  width:120px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#35424a;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 /*Media Queries*/
 @media(max-width: 768px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar,
  #newsletter form, #repaintgallery table{
   float:none;
   text-align:center;
   width: 100%;
  }

  header{
   padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  #showcase h1{
   margin-top: 40px;
  }

  #newsletter form button{
   display:block;
   width: 510px;
   margin:auto;
  }

  #newsletter form input[type="email"]{
   width:500px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
  }

  #repaintgallery img{
   width:170px;
   height:85px;
   margin:auto;
  }

  #repaintgallery table{
   display: block;
  }
  
  .download {
  width:60px;
  height:25px;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#35424a;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="kvxETPFss98nnIOWhaBbkHlKLAr3--nT5321XnFUVUg" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="FSX Repaints">
  <meta name="keywords" content="fsx, repaints, project airbus, just flight, pmdg, captainsim, premier airraft design, pad, airlines, project opensky, posky, tom's ruth">
  <meta name="author" content="Raven Lescano">
  <title>Repaints | Raven's Hangar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>

  <!-- favicon -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
  <meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="mstile-70x70.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mstile-150x150.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="mstile-310x150.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="mstile-310x310.png" />
   <body>
    <header>
     <div class="container">
     <div id="branding">
     <h1><span class="highlight">RAVEN'S</span> HANGAR</h1>
     </div>
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="repaints.html">Repaints</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </header>
    
    <section id="newsletter">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h1>
      <form>
       <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email....." ="">
       <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscibe</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section id="repaintgallery">
     <div class="gallery">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Repaints</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="img/template7.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/tnc.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template9.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/agn.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template10.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/cen.rar" download>Download</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="img/template3.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/ph.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template11.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/usao.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template17.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/ma.rar" download="ma.rar">Download</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="img/template15.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/PH75th.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template16.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/CEBN.rar" download>Download</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="img/template12.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/bin.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template13.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/as.rar" download>Download</a></td>
        <td><img src="img/template14.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/001.rar" download>Download</a></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
     <p>Raven's Hangar, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
    </footer>
   </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

IMG
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGoFg.jpg][1]

Try Here
[https://ravens-hangar.tk/repaints.html][1]

Comment: Can you share your code to snippet?

Comment: you can see it in the web to be sure [link](http://ravens-hangar.tk/repaints.html)

Comment: It says 404. In order to help you, you need to provide us the code properly, what your work so far.

Comment: There is the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use html tag  for link. just add a extra attribute download with it.

thats mean you can write

```
<a href="sample.jpg" download></a>
```

now file will prompt to download file with name sample.jpg

if you give value to download like;

```
<a href="sample.jpg" download="demo.jpg"></a>
```

then file will prompt to download with new name demo.jpg

try it and inform me about your problem.

Comment: should I remove this `type="application/octet-stream"`?

Comment: do you try with download attribute? first try it.

Comment: can you try it in you computer? I am doing this because a lot of our client can't download it because it opens

Comment: please give your full html <a> tag

Comment: `<a class="download" href="repaints/ma.rar" download="ma.rar">Download</a>`

Comment: as in now? or maybe I put this `<meta name="content-disposition" content="inline; filename=filename.rar">`